# Injection of a Interface that Inherits from a Bean

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, cdi, quarkus

I'm trying to create a custom MongoDB Repository that will handle transactions that are related to the business context only.

Since I want to expose these functions trough a interface, I'm having some trouble trying to inject the Interface on the service instead of the actual implementation, here's how it looks like ATM:

Interface:

```java
public interface MongoRepositoryActions<T> {
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);
}
```

Implementation

```java
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class BaseMongoRepository<T> implements MongoRepositoryActions<T> {

    @Inject
    MongoClient mongoClient;

    public <O extends T> O save(O object) {
        // Do some stuff related to the business.
        insertOperation(object);
        return object;
    }
}
```

Here's where I can't figure out how to use it.
The interface that I'm trying to expose:

```java
public interface FruitRepository extends MongoRepositoryActions<Fruit> {

}
```

The service layer that has the repository:

```java
import com.abinbev.b2b.core.MongoRepositoryActions;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class FruitService {

    @Inject
    MongoRepositoryActions<Fruit> fruitRepository; // This works fine

    @Inject
    FruitRepository repository; // This one doesn't

    public Fruit saveFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        return fruitRepository.save(fruit);
    }
}
```

So if I try to run the application by injecting the interface, I get this error:

```java
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.abinbev.b2b.core.fruit.FruitRepository and qualifiers [@Default]
```

I've also tried to annotate the interface, but didn't work as well.

Maybe I'm missing something.
Further information can be provided!
If necessary I can also push a reproducible example on my Github account.

Comment: Where is the implementation for `FruitRepository`?

Comment: The `BaseMongoRepository` class defines a bean with the following bean types: `BaseMongoRepository`, `MongoRepositoryActions`, `java.lang.Object`. That's why you can inject `MongoRepositoryActions`. In your code, there is _no_ bean with a bean type of `FruitRepository`. You can create one manually (`@ApplicationScoped class FruitRepositoryImpl extends MongoRepositoryActions<Fruit> implements FruitRepository {}`), or you can create a Quarkus extension that registers a synthetic bean for each repository interface. However, Quarkus already provides that: https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache

Comment: @mtj I want to inject the `FruitRepository` to use its inherited methods.

Comment: @Ladicek I'm trying to achieve something similar to `quarkus-mongodb-panache`, actually I'm writing a mongo-client-wrapper that will handle some business rules that are commons between several micro-services. The idea is to inject the interface instead of the implementation.

Comment: @JohnnesSouza There's nothing wrong with trying to inject an interface instead of a concrete class, but the implementation must still be present and known to the container. You can either implement it explicitly, or write an extension to create it on the fly (see https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html), but you cannot simply expect the container to magically conjure a class which satisfies your interface. As for extensions, I am not sure whether they even work with quarkus, as I never tried.